# Add a Highlighted content web part in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I’m relatively new when it comes to having knowledge regarding “Highlighted content web part” 
Based on some post I figured it out that it can be used to filter and sort to narrow down and organize the content

How do I add a “Highlighted content web part” inside a modern experience document library?
I want to use the feature of Sort by : Most viewed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to make it easier for end users to find the daily use files. Add the Highlight content web part to home page shall be easier to for them to search for files. Or just sort by the last modified date. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Web parts can be added to the home page or other pages that you've added. We can't add web parts to the document library pages. Document libraries do have "views", which can specify which filters and what sort order to use to display the documents. Unfortunately, number of views isn't one of the options for the document library "view".

Comment: What would you recommend on doing? Already using views and filtering. 
I was looking for a way to display the most frequently used items in the document library, so the users don’t have to filter and customize views.

Comment: you could certainly add that web part to a different page, but unfortunately, sorting a library itself by popularity isn't an option, afaik.

Comment: @ Mike2500, what would you recommend considering the fact that our document library has a lot of files and only a few are daily used. I don't know which of the files are mostly used but my idea is to find a way so when the user goes to the document library, there are shown the most used files as default

Comment: In SP online, you can pin docs to the top of the library. Or, sort by date modified descending. Or, display the "version" field and sort by version descending (this will get the documents that have been changed the most to the top).